# installing nuget packages with multiple sources (two corp and two Microsoft) won't install unless VPN connected

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Does anyone know why Visual Studio won't install nuget packages when you have
-two corporate nuget sources
-two default Microsoft sources
-VPN not turned on (it's the weekend, I figured I wouldn't need the VPN)

This weekend I tried to install a nuget package (autofac) but since I wasn't connected to VPN, nuget failed. I've had this before with previous VS versions, so this isn't new. When you have multiple nuget sources (doesn't matter listing order), VS refuses to connect to other internet sources to install any\all packages. Note, I am indeed connected to the web, hardwired connection and wifi, browsing completely works as does anything else on any other ports.

Why can't nuget just skip over the corporate ones? If it's going to find autofac anyways on the internet, just use those sources. Oh, and I COULD remove the corporate sources, but then I am going to need them come Monday morning. So why don't I connect VPN? Well, that's what I have to do. But that's my question, why do I HAVE to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a try to disable(not remove) the source in Tools/Nuget Package Manger/Package Source

Comment: I seem to remember unchecking them from the nuget options, but they still don't work when in the list.

Comment: If so, we suggest you report it to developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem

Comment: Ironic, I did, and they suggested reporting it here. HAHA Recursion?  LOL

Comment: If possible, could you share the link here